# Fitting a specific curve to data using fitModel, plotPoints, and plotFun {mosaic} in a loop function

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to fit a specific curve, Y = 1 - B^d, this data:

```
Sample  depth   cumulative_biomass
16  5   0.673619861
16  10  0.901351445
16  20  0.978845297
16  30  0.997329897
16  40  0.999999999
20  5   0.354862317
20  10  0.604891262
20  20  0.840608605
20  30  0.946156329
20  40  0.999999999
27  5   0.708857614
27  10  0.844267599
27  20  0.928009919
27  30  0.97231086
27  40  0.999999999
40  5   0.856355217
40  10  0.917790117
40  20  0.965147407
40  30  0.986819053
40  40  1
```

where Y is 'cumulative biomass' and d is 'depth'. I want to fit the curve represented by this equation and solve for B. This works with the following code:

```
library(mosaic)
data<-read.table("example.txt",header=T, na.strings="NA")
str(data)
sample16=subset(data, Sample == "16")
m<-fitModel(cumulative_biomass~ 1 - B^depth, data=sample16)
coef(m)
summary(m)
str(m)
plotPoints(cumulative_biomass~depth,xlab = "depth (cm)", ylab= "Cumulative Biomass", data=sample16)
plotFun(m(depth)~depth,depth.lim=range(0, 40), add=TRUE)
```

I would like to run this in a loop function (I have hundreds of samples). The model seems to work in the loop- it solves the B for each independent sample. However, I want to check the fit of the model, and for some reason, the graphing component does not work- I want it to output into either a PDF or image document, but when it works, it simply takes the first set of 5 points, plots them on the first graph, and in each subsequent graph, plots the line for the new sample model on top of the points of the first sample. Here is the code:

```
samplez <- c( 16, 20,  27,  40) 
#start of the loop
z<-lapply(unique(samplez),function(i)
{data_sample <- subset(data,data$Sample==i) 
 m<-fitModel(cumulative_biomass~ 1 - B^depth, data=data_sample)
                                estimate <- coef(m)

                                plot<-plotPoints(cumulative_biomass~depth,xlab = "depth (cm)", 
                                ylab = "Cumulative     Biomass", data=data_sample)
                                plot<-plotFun(m(depth)~depth,depth.lim=range(0, 40), add=T),data=data_sample)
                                pdf(file = paste("sample",i,".pdf",sep=""))
                                dev.off()
                                c(i,estimate)

})
out <- do.call("rbind", z)
colnames(out) <- c("sample","B")
```

Comment: You should open the `pdf` file _before_  you call any plot. `pdf(file=...)` should go before any call to `plotPoints` in the loop.